# Split one column into multiple (quantity and names unknown)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider I have a table like this:

**Example**

```
ID    Name    Something    Params
-----------------------------------------
1     First   A241FRT      P1=12, P2=One
2     Second  G924PEM      P1=19
3     Third   L9449TY      P1=94, P2=Two
```

I need to split column `Params` into multiple. So I need to get something like this:

**Expected result**

```
ID    Name    Something    P1    P2
-----------------------------------------
1     First   A241FRT      12    One
2     Second  G924PEM      19
3     Third   L9449TY      94    Two
```

I don't know the names of extra columns as so as it's quantity. 
I'm not really good at SQL, so I strongly need your help, thanks to everyone

Comment: Whether your column `pattern` will contain similar pattern value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would convert the params into a json value and then extract the keys:

```
select id, name, something, 
       params ->> 'P1' as p1,
       params ->> 'P2' as p2
from (
  select id, 
         name, 
         something, 
         concat('{', 
                  regexp_replace(regexp_replace(params, '(P[0-9])=', '"\1":', 'gi'), 
                                 ':(\w+)', ':"\1"', 'gi'), 
                '}')::jsonb
  from the_table
) t
```

---

If you need that often, it probably makes sense to create a function that converts the "params" to a JSON representation:

```
create function params_to_json(p_params text)
  returns jsonb
as
$$
  select jsonb_object_agg(split_part(p, '=', 1), split_part(p, '=', 2))
  from regexp_split_to_table(p_params, ',\s*') as t(p)
$$
language sql
stable
;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select id, name, something, 
       params_to_json(params) ->> 'P1' as p1,
       params_to_json(params) ->> 'P2' as p2
from data
```

The function is more flexible with regards to unknown keys as it only assumes that key/value pairs are separated by a `,` and key and value are separated by a `=`

Comment: nicely answered